# Как получить дамп БД в SQL виде?

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

Как снять дамп БД в SQL виде?

Чтобы на другой БД можно было просто вставлять данные таблиц.
Пробовал через PL/SQL Deveoloper, но он не вносит даты в кaвычки.

Может быть есть какие то другие средства? Есть ли такое, например, в TOAD?

Comment: А зачем это вообще нужно? Почему нельзя просто сделать обычный нормальный дамп? Нужно обязательно именно инсертить данные?

Comment: Да.

Comment: Потому что заказчик просит именно так..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) умеет экспортировать данные из таблиц в виде набора выражений INSERT.

В случае, если нужно сделать полную копию базы, то лучше воспользоваться оракловыми утилитами [exp и imp](http://wiki.oracle.com/page/Oracle+export+and+import+)

Comment: А где именно в sql deveoloper куда заходить не подскажете..?

Comment: Правый клик на конкретной таблице, в меню выбрать "Export...". Далее следовать указаниям.

Comment: Спасибо, А не подскажете где в нем можно изменить формат выгружаемой даты?

Comment: Зачем менять формат, если значения для дат вставляются через вызов функции to_date? Дата - это не строковый тип, и формат менять не надо, т.к. это не отразится на вставке данных.

Answer (score 2):

Если на целевой БД уже существует структура таблиц и надо только добавить данные с другой БД, то с этой задачей отлично справится *Data Pump* с параметром `CONTENT`.

С этим параметром  загрузка данных будет полностью эквивалентна `INSERT INTO ...` операции. Плюс преимущества: будет быстрей, обеспечит загрузку LOB, позаботится о порядке вставки в соответствии с референциальными ограничениями.

Например создадим тестовые таблицы:

```sql
create table t1 (id number primary key);
create table t2 (id number, memo varchar2 (32), 
    constraint fk1 foreign key (id) references t1 (id));

insert all into t1 values (r) into t2 values (r, 'memo '||r)
select rownum r from dual connect by level<=100;
commit;
```

Создадим дамп только данных этих таблиц:

```
$ expdp iam/pass@srv/svc schemas=iam include="table:\"in ('T1','T2')\"" content=data_only\
      directory=data_pump_dir dumpfile=dataonly.dmp logfile=expdo.log
```

Удалим данные из таблиц, т.е. сделаем их целевыми:

```
truncate table t2;    
truncate table t1;
```

Теперь загрузим данные:

```
$ impdp iam/pass@srv/svc content=data_only \
      directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=dataonly.dmp logfile=impdo.log
```

В результате теперь таблицы заполнены новыми данными:

```
select count (*) from t1 natural join t2;

  COUNT(*)
----------
       100
```